# Meaning of `leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage` in Apache Kafka Configuration

Tags: apache-kafka

Going through the kafka docs, I found this particular configuration. `leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage`.

What does `leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage` mean intuitively? How can I simulate the working of this configuration?

```
Type:   int
Default:    10
Valid Values:   
Importance: high
Update Mode:    read-only
```

Why is the value `10` as default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage` defines the percentage of non-preferred leaders allowed. If the ratio goes over this value on a broker, and `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` is true, Kafka will automatically move the leadership for these partitions onto the preferred leader.

If a partition has multiple replicas, any of them can become the leader however there is always a preferred one. The preferred leader is the replica listed first in the replica list. For example, in the following Broker 0 is the preferred leader:

```
Topic:test    PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:
    Topic: test    Partition: 0    Leader: 0    Replicas: 0,2,1    Isr: 0,2,1
```

By default, this setting is set to 10, so Kafka allows up to 10% of leaders to be on non-preferred replicas before electing the preferred replicas again.

Comment: Thanks, Could you point me to any website where internal working of kafka like the above is explained clearly?